# Efficient algorithm to create a tree where you know each elements path

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, parent-child, time-complexity

This is probably quite an easy question to answer but for some reason my mind has been blank and I've been unable to come up with an efficient solution.

The task is as so: I have a number of elements, which contain an array(their path) and their name. And I want to create a tree from this list in the format(the specific syntax with symbols is not important)

```
Elements:
  ( name: Element 1,
    Elements:
      ( name: Element 1.1
      )
    Name: Element 2,
    Elements: 
      ( ... )
  )
```

So given items in the following style, do you have any suggestions for an algorithm to solve this task as efficiently as possible.

The item style is: `[ Great Grandfather, Grandfather, Father ], Element Name`.

And the number of elements to the route could be any number. The only obvious solution I can come up with is by starting at the first item in each of the parent arrays and add those to the tree if they don't exist, then move onto `Parents[1]` then  `Parents[2]` etc... Any ideas?

Comment: Is the input topologically sorted, i.e. is it guaranteed that a parent node appears before all of its children?

Comment: It would help to give an example of what the input would actually look like. Also, are you limited to 3 levels, or could you have [u,v,w,x,y,z],elem_name?

Comment: @dhke, Yes. The order is guaranteed that the parents will always be before their children in the array, and that the first parent is always the one from the root node.

Comment: @user3386109, There can be any number of levels. So for example item1: [Household, Kitchen] name: Fridge. Item2: [Office] name: Desk

Comment: Doing what you suggest is O(1) per node you want to add.  Is this not efficient enough for you?  What do you suspect you could do instead? If you can be sure the data is already sorted it could help bt since the root of the tree is likely to be in the CPU cache you might not find this makes much difference. i.e. it is the adding of leaf nodes which is the real code.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I guess it may be a case where I've been writing it down and thought my solution wasn't efficient enough. Now I feel like I've been quite stupid asking a question I've already answered.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but when you reach a time complexity which is basically O(1) per operation, you can't do much better. (You can reduce the factor, but the CPU is likely to be smart enough to reduce it for you)

Comment: More feel quite silly about not releasing the complexity I had. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two approaches. The simpler one is `O(n d ln b)`, with `d` being the maximum depth and `b` the branching factor, i.e. the maximum/average number of children per parent. You might assume these constant (and hence use `O(n)`), but they are probably functionally dependent on `n`.

The other one is `O(n)` time but may degrade to quadratic for bad hash functions and other reasons.

**Version 1**

- each node keeps an ordered list of its children.
- from root down, find next child, i.e.
  if the path is `A.B.C`, find `A`, then recurse into `A` and find `B`.
  finally insert `C` as child of `B` (if `C` does not exist).

  Use [`binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) to find the insertion point (or the matching element).

Since the list of children is sorted, the individual search is `O(ln(b))` with `b` the maximum number of children. You need to go at worst `d` levels deep, so `O(d ln(b))`. The whole thing needs to repeat `n` times.

**Version 2**

This is more memory intensive and might not actually be faster.

While building the tree, keep a map *path-to-node -> node*.

Whenever you encounter a node the input

- lookup the node's parent by path inside the map (`O(1)`).
- append the child to the parent and store the full path of the new node in the map.

If you assume the hash table works as advertised, you get `O(n)` (or `O(n ln(n))` if the children are sorted) but need to have enough memory for the hash table.

Since Version 2 seems not that much better, I'd stick with Version 1 which is simpler to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first one seems ideal, and shouldnt be too hard to implement. Again, thank you.